# Volume of products - stoichiometry

Tags: gas-laws, stoichiometry

> $\rm 20\,cm^3$ of ethyne, $\ce{C2H2}$, is reacted with $\rm 500 \,cm^3$ of oxygen.
>   The equation for the reaction is:
>
> $$\ce{2C2H2(g) + 5O2(g) → 4CO2(g) + 2H2O(l)}$$
>
> What is the total volume of gas remaining at the end of the reaction?
>
> (all volumes are measured at room temperature and pressure)

**My effort**: I think the answer should be $510\,\mathrm{cm^3}$ because the volume of the leftover oxygen is $450\,\mathrm{cm^3}$ and the volume of the products is $60\,\mathrm{cm^3}$ but the answer is $490\,\mathrm{cm^3}$. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: 490 cc seems to be the correct answer. Please show your work, and I would be happy to help you find your mistake.

Comment: Because they count water as liquid, that's why.

Comment: I think you failed to notice that one of your products, i.e water is a liquid, and thus will not contribute to the total gas volume at the end of the reaction.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a breakdown: First, you identify that ethyne is the limiting reagent and would be consumed completely. Second, you correctly calculated the volume of oxygen left that is $450\ \mathrm{cm^3}$. $20\ \mathrm{cm^3}$ of ethyne will completely react to produce $40\ \mathrm{cm^3}$ of carbon dioxide.

Thus, the total gas volume when the reaction reaches completion is $490\ \mathrm{cm^3}$.